# Calculate. $\int_0^{\frac \pi 6}\cos 3x\ dx$

Tags: integration

How do you integrate
$$
\int_0^{\frac \pi 6}\cos 3x\ dx
$$
Any help much appreciated, my main issue is integrating the upper limit. I'm not quiet sure how to go about it.

Any help much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: make pi by typing `$\pi$` $\pi$

Comment: Are you familiar with integrals as anti-derivates?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$u =3x, \space \frac{1}{3}du = dx$$

$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{6} \cos 3x \space dx = \frac{1}{3} \int\cos u \space dx = \frac{1}{3} \sin u \implies \frac{1}{3} \sin 3x \Big|_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x)~dx ~=~ \frac{1}{k}\int_{ka}^{kb}f\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)~dx\quad(k \neq 0)$$

Comment: Sorry but this seems at best anecdotal. Much better to enable the OP to compute a primitive of the function without remembering this trick.

Comment: I don't think that expanding and contracting the interval of integration is a *trick*, and it should help the poster simplify the integral so that an appropriate primitive can be found.

Comment: The trouble is that your answer leads the OP to believe that they should avoid considering directly a primitive of $x\mapsto\cos(3x)$. I believe this is a disservice to the OP since the opposite is true, they should be able to compute *on the spot* a primitive of this function, without preliminarily "simplifying the integral".

Answer (score 0):

The antiderivative is $\frac{1}{3} \sin{3x}$ (why?). Now use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. For the upper limit, we have $\frac{1}3 \sin({\frac{3\pi}{6}}) = \frac{1}3\sin{\frac{\pi}2} = \frac{1}3 = I$ since plugging in the lower limit yields $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) explains the connection between derivatives and integrals.  In some sense they are opposites like addition and subtraction (there's more to it than that, but that may be a good way to start thinking about it).

So, what we're looking for is a function whose derivative is $\cos (3x)$. Let's focus on the cosine portion and worry about the argument after.  When dealing with trigonometric functions, a good place to start is usually with another trigonometric function!  If you differentiate $A\sin (g(x))$ you will get $A\cos(g(x))\frac{dg}{dx}$ by applying the chain rule.

Alright, this will give us what we were looking for.  Comparing this to the original question, clearly $g(x) = 3x$.  Now we need $A \frac{dg}{dx} = 3A$ to be $1$ (this is by comparing the coefficients).  From here, $A = 1/3$.  Now we have our anti-derivative $F(x) = \frac{1}{3} \sin(3x)$.  Again, going back to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we need to apply the limits $F(\pi/6)-F(0) = \frac{1}{3} \sin(\pi/2) - \frac{1}{3} \sin(0) = \frac{1}{3}$.

I hope that helps!